# Picasso failing to load image from FilePath

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading

I am trying to load the image I get from Gallery app. Then I get the URI from the `data.getData().getPath()`. I get the path which looks like this:

**file:///-1/1/content%3A/media/external/file/10393/ORIGINAL/NONE/453874796**

What kind of path is this? What is it called?

However when I pass it to Picasso for loading the image from this path, I get exception.

```
execption: /-1/1/content:/media/external/file/10393/ORIGINAL/NONE/453874796: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

How can I load the image from this path? Here is the code:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getContext())
                .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                        //Here your log
                        Log.e("error", "uri: "+ uri +" execption: "+ exception.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }).build();

        picasso
                .load(new File(path))
                .into(mProfileImage);
```

All the permissions have been granted to the app.

Comment: I recommend you to use `UniversalImageLoader`..!!

Comment: Make sure you have added read, write permissions in your manifest file

Comment: I am already using piacsso, so I would love to understand how can I acheive the desired result

Comment: use this while loading image `.load(Uri.parse(yourpath));`

Comment: What kind of path is this?

Comment: Same issue. My path looks like /file:/0/1/content:/media/external/images/media/860/ORIGINAL/NONE/1611454405

Comment: any solution so far?